# How to load external JS from disk in a VS code extension?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my vs code extension I want to integrate a preview of a diagram which requires external JS. In a normal web page I can simply use:

```
<script src='myscript.js'></script>
```

but this doesn't work in a vscode extension. I tried all possible folders (root, src, out, out/src) to no avail. How can I load my script actually?

Answer (score 0):

Its an older question, still answering so that people can see how to do it.

You have to first *expose property* inside **package.json** and use that property as a reference inside your code. Later on when the extension is installed from market-place, you have to ask its users to *override the property* that you exposed earlier on the **.vscode/setting.json**.

Comment: could you show us the details on how to do it ?